# Firefox plugin for SSL

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to make a plugin for Mozilla which prints simple SSL details like Name and certificate is valid till what date.

Here is my CODE :

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var text_entry = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 412,
  height: 400,
  contentURL: data.url("text-entry.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("get-text.js")
});

require("sdk/widget").Widget({
  label: "Text entry",
  id: "text-entry",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",    
  panel: text_entry,    
});
text_entry.on("show", function() {
  text_entry.port.emit("show");
});

text_entry.port.on("text-entered", function (text) {
  console.log(text);  

var requrl = require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.url;
console.log(requrl);

const {Ci,Cc} = require("chrome");
  //var req = new XMLHttpRequest();


var req = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
req.open('GET', requrl, false);
req.onload = function(e) {
 console.log(req);
let channel = req.channel;
console.log(requrl);

   if (! channel instanceof  Ci.nsIChannel) {
        console.log("No channel available\n");
        return;
    }
console.log(requrl);

var secInfo = req.securityInfo;
var cert = secInfo.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatusProvider).SSLStatus.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatus).serverCert    ;
var validity = cert.validity.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIX509CertValidity);

console.log(requrl);


  console.log("\tCommon name (CN) = " + cert.commonName + "\n");
  console.log("\tOrganisation = " + cert.organization + "\n");
  console.log("\tIssuer = " + cert.issuerOrganization + "\n");
  console.log("\tSHA1 fingerprint = " + cert.sha1Fingerprint + "\n");       
  console.log("\tValid from " + validity.notBeforeGMT + "\n");
  console.log("\tValid until " + validity.notAfterGMT + "\n");


 };

});
```

It says, XMLHttpRequest is not defined. Also the channel structure is empty when printed to console.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is not available in the context of `main.js`. Do you actually call the `send` method of `req`?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure where your code is broken or why (as I'm to lazy to replicate the missing pieces like the `text-entry.html`).

Anyway, here is a fast test that works for me in both, and SDK add-on and Scratchpad:

```
// Save as your main.js.
// Alternatively execute in a Scratchpad in about:newTab.
var sdk = false;
if (!("Cc" in this)) {
  try {
    // add-on SDK version
    this.Cc = require("chrome").Cc;
    this.Ci = require("chrome").Ci;
    this.log = console.error.bind(console);
    this.sdk = true;
    log("using SDK");
  }
  catch (ex) {
    // Scratchpad on about:newtab version
    this.Cc = Components["classes"];
    this.log = console.log.bind(console);
    log("using scratchpad");
  }
}
let r = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
  .createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
r.open("GET", "https://tn123.org/");
r.onloadend = function(e) {
  let ok = "OK";
  try {
    log(e);
    // Note: instanceof is an implicit QueryInterface!
    log(this.channel instanceof Ci.nsIChannel);
    log(this.channel.securityInfo instanceof Ci.nsISSLStatusProvider);
    let status, cert;
    log(status = this.channel.securityInfo.SSLStatus);
    log(status.cipherName);
    log(cert = status.serverCert);
    log("Common name (CN) = " + cert.commonName);
    log("Organisation = " + cert.organization);
    log("Issuer = " + cert.issuerOrganization);
    log("SHA1 fingerprint = " + cert.sha1Fingerprint);       
    log("Valid from " + cert.validity.notBeforeGMT);
    log("Valid until " + cert.validity.notAfterGMT);
    for (let k of Object.keys(cert)) {
      if (k[0].toUpperCase() === k[0]) {
        // skip constants
        continue;
      }
      let v = cert[k];
      if (typeof v === "function") {
        continue;
      }
      log(k + ": " + v);
    }
  }
  catch (ex) {
    log("Caught exception", ex);
    ok = ex;
  }
  if (sdk) {
   require("notifications").notify({
     title: "Test done",
     text: "HTTPS test done; result=" + ok
   });
  }
  log("HTTPS test done; result=" + ok);
};
r.send();
```

PS: I'm using `console.error` in the SDK, [because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/console):

> If you're developing your add-on using the Extension Auto-installer,
>   then the add-on is installed in Firefox, meaning that messages will
>   appear in the Browser Console. But see the discussion of logging
>   levels: by default, messages logged using log(), info(), trace(), or
>   warn() won't be logged in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written this in the content script? If so, you can't make requests from the content script (which is why it says it does not exist). You need to write this in main.js. If you want to communicate with your content script (html, window, etc) you'll have to use message passing: port.emit and addon.emit to send messages and port.on and addon.on to listen for messages.